# Can't sort mat-table

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I'm trying to use mat-sort-header from angular material in order to sort a table.

I get the data contained in the table from a http request. The data is displayed fine but the sorting doesn't seem to work. I can see the emitted events when I click on the columns, but rows keep the same order.

I've seen that some people already had this issue, so I tried the following :

- wrapping the `this.dataSource.sort = this.sort` inside a setTimeOut
- doing this inside ngOnViewInit

Here is my html template :

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="nagiosData" matSort (matSortChange)="sortData($event)">

        <ng-container matColumnDef="hostName">
          <th mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef> Host name </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.hostName}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="pluginOutput">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Plugin output </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.pluginOutput}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="currentState">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> State </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <span *ngIf="element.currentState == 0; else red" class="dot"></span>
          </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="services">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Services </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> <button mat-raised-button color="primary">See Services</button> </td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

      </table>


    </div>

    <ng-template #red>
      <span class="redDot"></span>
    </ng-template>
```

and my Component :

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import {DataLoaderService} from '../data-loader.service';
import {MatPaginator, MatTableDataSource, MatSort, MatTable} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nagios-view',
  templateUrl: './nagios-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nagios-view.component.css']
})
export class NagiosViewComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  public data = [];
  public nagiosData = [];


  displayedColumns: string[] = ['hostName', 'pluginOutput', 'currentState', 'services'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;

  @ViewChild(MatTable) table: MatTable<any>;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  constructor(private dls: DataLoaderService) { }

 public loadNagiosData(){
    this.dls.getNagiosInfo().subscribe( data => {
      this.nagiosData = JSON.parse(data.mesureList[0].description).hosts;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.nagiosData);

      setTimeout(() => {
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      });

    })
  }

  sortData(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // this.loadData();
    this.loadNagiosData();
  }
```

The data I get from http is an array of elements with the following structure :

```
{hostName: "someHostName", pluginOutput: "someString", services: Array(8), currentState: "0"}
```

Thank you

Comment: I don't see any sorting component in your HTML, did you forgot to add it ?

Comment: What do you mean ? I did as in the angular material examples, i.e I use ```matSort``` in my ```table``` tag, and I add ```mat-sort-header``` for each column I want to sort the data by

Comment: I mean that you have a [sorting component](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview), and if you didn't write the HTML for your view child, you're actually binding `undefined` to your data source.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I solved the issue by implementing my own sorting function when the `matSortChange` event is triggered, just like in the `mat-sort-header` example. But this is weird because they don't need to do this in the other examples.